# XCode how to check object is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm now stuck that I cannot check when Object is NULL in Objective C.

Here is result from NSLog when I get vale from **_detail.CompanyImg**.

```
_detail.CompanyImg text = (null)
```

and following is checking whether object is null or not.

```
if (_detail.CompanyImg &&  && [_detail.CompanyImg length] > 0) {
```

but encountered following error even tried like that.

> [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bcaa4c0

Comment: are you confusing NULL and nil ? try to check for != nil

Comment: i've already tried with nil it does not work.

Comment: `CompanyImg` length? it is a string then.. Bad naming..

Comment: @0yeoj it does matter?

Comment: No, i just got confuse at the first look..

Comment: It's NSString object and will include image-string-from-url

Answer (score 3):

The object `_detail.CompanyImg` is clearly an instance of `NSNull` which isn't strictly `nil`.  It's a special-case as it's impossible to hold null values in Objective-C collection classes, so in cases where it must be represented the `NSNull` class is used.

If you know that this is possible, then this will work:

```
if (!_detail.CompanyImg || _detail.CompanyImg == [NSNull null]) {
    // it's null
}
```

Note: `NSNull` is a special-case in its ability to use `==` for comparison; normally you'd use `isEqual` or `isKindOfClass`.

Comment: encounter error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10752f4c0'

Comment: @ppshein This is the same error.  The object is `NSNull` but it's being treated as `NSString`.  You need to check its type before invoking string-specific methods upon it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by

```
if (object == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    //do something
}
```

or

```
if (object isEqual:[NSNull null]) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: still encountered following error : [NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10687b4c0

Comment: don't use `isEqualToString` use `isEqual` @ppshein

Answer (score 0):

nil or NULL values can't be stored as-is in `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

You have to store it as a special value `[NSNull null]`.

JSON parsers will report null values as `[NSNUll null]` in general.

[NSNull null] is an object, so `[NSNull null] == nil` is FALSE and `[NSNull null] != nil` is TRUE.

So you should try:

```
if (_detail.CompanyImg && detail.CompanyImg != [NSNUll null] && [_detail.CompanyImg length] > 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Or check the class:

```
if (_[detail.CompanyImg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [_detail.CompanyImg length] > 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my checking made no error at all.

```
if (_detail.CompanyImg != [NSNull null]) {
```